# Unique Picklist Values

Tags: picklist, calendar, form, schedule

I have a visualforce page that allows customers to schedule an appointment with me. The fields I have are subject, description, date, and time. Since I'm only available at certain time blocks throughout the day, I'm using a picklist for the time field. If one person selects a certain time and date, how do I make it so that others cannot pick the same time and date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can build your own set of [SelectOption](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) objects in your controller and set the `isDisabled` flag to true for the times that have already been booked. You would make the `value` strings match the picklist values. The Visualforce [apex:selections](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm) tag links those options up to the input field.

This of course assumes that you have some booking data objects to query to work out which times are occupied. Occasionally the time will be free when the page is opened but booked by the time the selected time is saved; in that case you can ask the user to pick again.

Comment: Alternatively, you can choose only to show the not selected times by restricting the query, which might be a even easier approach.